# Value of second-derivative of twice differentiable function?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $g(x)$ is a twice differentiable function and $g(1) = 1$; $g(2) = 4$; $g(3) = 9$. Which of the following is necessarily true?

(A) $g''(x) = 3$ for some $x$ belonging to $[1, 2]$

(B) $g''(x) = 5$ for some $x$ belonging to $[2, 3]$

(C) $g''(x) = 2$ for some $x$ belonging to $[1, 3]$

(D) $g''(x) = 2$ for some $x$ belonging to $[1.5, 2.5]$

Correct answer is (D).

I figured that $g(x) = x^2$, and therefore its second derivative must be $2$ in any interval. My understanding is clearly incorrect; please help me understand why $g''(x)=2$ is not necessarily true for all $x$. Am I missing something extremely obvious? I am so embarrassed!

Comment: If (D) is correct then so is (C) isn't it?

Comment: Just because $x^2$ fits the data doesn't mean that it is the only function that $g$ could be.  There are an infinite number of other choices.  Just among the polynomials, there are higher degree polynomials that would work.  These would not have a constant second derivative.

Comment: Final clarification- when we are told a polynomial is $n$ times differentiable, does it mean the polynomial is exactly of degree $n$, or *at least* $n$?

Comment: By example, let $g(x)=x^2\cos(2\pi x)$, then $$g''(x)=-4 \pi ^2 x^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)-8 \pi  x \sin (2 \pi  x)+2 \cos (2 \pi  x)\neq 2$$

Comment: @Andy : Every polynomial is infinitely times differentiable. Most of those derivatives will be zero. It makes thus no sense to talk about polynomials that are "only" $n$ times differentiable. - A piecewise cubic function can also be twice continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the second power $x^2$ has the indicated function values. Using the difference $f(x)=g(x)-x^2$ you get a function with 3 roots. You can now apply Rolle's theorem twice (or thrice, depending on what you count) to find that $f''(x)=0$ at some point in the interval.

You can also consider $h(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ where $h'(x)=0$ implies $f'(x)=f'(x+1)$ at that point, which may give a little more control on the intermediate points generated by Rolle's theorem.

However, you can also piece together $C^2$ functions that are linear on $[1.5,2.5]$ with the given values.